# Exception: UTFDataFormat in processMarshaller

Tags: marshalling, drools, unmarshalling, jbpm

I came across to an issue when I upgrade my drools and jbpm version to the below given specification, while I try to push the Task from one process to another process "UTFDataFormat" Exception found in the readProcessInstance. I am quite confused to use the same. Could you please check and advise me.

**Specifications:-**
jBPM: 5.4.0-Final
drools: 5.5.0-Final

```
Code:-  
            WorkflowProcess workFlowProcess = getWorkflowProcess(kbase);
            BpmnRoute baseRoute = constructBpmnRoute(workFlowProcess);
            ProcessInstanceInfo processInstanceInfo = processInstanceInfos.get(0);
            InputStream file = new ByteArrayInputStream( processInstanceInfo.getProcessInstanceByteArray() );
            InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream( file );
            InternalRuleBase ruleBase = (InternalRuleBase) ((KnowledgeBaseImpl) kbase).ruleBase;
            InternalWorkingMemory wm = (InternalWorkingMemory) ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
            RuleFlowProcessInstanceMarshaller processMarshaller;
            MarshallerReaderContext context = new MarshallerReaderContext(buffer, ruleBase, null, null, ProtobufMarshaller.TIMER_READERS, new EnvironmentImpl());
            context.wm = wm;
            processMarshaller = RuleFlowProcessInstanceMarshaller.INSTANCE;
            ObjectInputStream stream = context.stream;
            stream.readUTF();
           WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl processInstance = (WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl) processMarshaller.readProcessInstance(context);
            context.close(); 

Exception:-
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
17:12:21,747 ERROR [stderr] (http--10.0.5.53-8080-2) at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java:3107)
17:12:21,747 ERROR [stderr] (http--10.0.5.53-8080-2) at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3051)
17:12:21,747 ERROR [stderr] (http--10.0.5.53-8080-2) at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
17:12:21,748 ERROR [stderr] (http--10.0.5.53-8080-2) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1072)
17:12:21,748 ERROR [stderr] (http--10.0.5.53-8080-2) at org.jbpm.marshalling.impl.AbstractProcessInstanceMarshaller.readProcessInstance(AbstractProcessInstanceMarshaller.java:378)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that these two lines in your code:

```
ObjectInputStream stream = context.stream;
stream.readUTF();
```

interfere with the unmarshalling of the saved object, which is being done in the subsequent call to readProcessInstance. Thus, the call to readUTF from this method fails. - Omit these two lines and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried removing the above two lines, but no changes there. I doubt the object "context" of class MarshallerReaderContext having passed incorrect data in args. Could you please advise me.